Registerf UNKNOWN service in eureka discovery server
spring-boot version 3.2.5
eureka server version 4.1.1
eureka client version 4.1.3
Here is the eureka config
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    fetch-registry: true
    register-with-eureka: true
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka

ACCOUNTS    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 192.168.0.138:accounts:8090
UNKNOWN n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 192.168.0.138.
this unknown service gets registered.
how to solve it.
I really appreciate any help you can provide.
